# Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I have read some resources and I found out how hierarchical clustering works. However, when I compare it with k-means clustering, it seems to me that k-means really constitues specific number of clusters,whereas hierarchical analysis shows me how the samples can be clustered. What I mean is that I do not get a specific number of clusters in hierarchical clustering. I get only a scheme about how the clusters can be constituted and portion of relation between the samples.

Thus, I cannot understand where I can use this clustering method.

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical clustering (HC) is just another distance-based clustering method like k-means. The number of clusters can be roughly determined by [cutting the dendrogram represented by HC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/where-to-cut-a-dendrogram). Determining the number of clusters in a data set is not an easy task for all clustering methods, which is usually based on your applications. Tuning the thresholds in HC may be more explicit and straightforward for researchers, especially for a very large data set. I think [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66128/choosing-the-number-of-clusters-in-hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering) is also related.

Answer (score 1):

In k-means clustering k is a hyperparameter that you need to find in order to divide your data points into clusters whereas in hierarchical clustering (lets take one type of hierarchical clustering i.e. agglomerative) firstly you consider all the points in your dataset as a cluster and then merge two clusters based on a similarity metric and repeat this until you get a single cluster. I will explain this with an example.

Suppose initially you have 13 points (x_1,x_2,....,x_13) in your dataset so at start you will have 13 clusters, now in second step lets you get 7 clusters (x_1-x_2 , x_4-x_5, x_6-x_8, x_3-x_7, x_11-x_12, x_10, x_13) based on the similarity between the points. In the third step lets say you get 4 clusters(x_1-x_2-x_4-x_5, x_6-x_8-x_10, x_3-x_7-x_13, x_11-x_12) like this you would arrive to a step wherein all the points in your dataset form one cluster and which is also the last step of agglomerative clustering algorithm.
So in hierarchical clustering, there is no hyperparameter, depending upon your problem, if you want 7 clusters then stop at the second step if you want 4 clusters then stop at the third step and likewise.

A practical advantage in hierarchical clustering is the possibility of visualizing results using dendrogram. If you don’t know in advance what number of clusters you’re looking for (as is often the case…), you can use the dendrogram plot that can help you choose k with no need to create separate clusterings. Dendrogram can also give a great insight into the data structure, help identify outliers, etc. Hierarchical clustering is also deterministic, whereas k-means with random initialization can give you different results when running several times on the same data.

Hope this helps.